# Delete ACF Value Based off another value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I am hoping someone could please assist with the below snippet, I need for one of my fields values to be deleted when a different select field is changed to complete.

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');
function my_acf_save_post($post_id){

$status = get_field('status');
    if ('complete', $status){
        delete_field('project_address');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the "post_id" to select the value and delete the value. Logic it true, I think.

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post');
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ){

$status = get_field( 'status', $post_id );
  if ( 'complete' === $status ){
      delete_field( 'project_address', $post_id );
  }
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: This is a good answer, you could improve this by using strict comparison in your if statement `===` or `!==` rather than `==` see https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/#clever-code and the comment on loose comparison.

Comment: thank for your instructions. I will keep improving on following standard. I also updated the answer

Comment: Thank you for the response, I went ahead and tested this and when I change my status field to complete it doesn’t delete the entry in my project address field. The project address field is a google map field, not sure if that would prevent the entry from being deleted. I haven’t used delete_field before.

Comment: `get_field( 'status', $post_id )` and `delete_field( 'project_address', $post_id )` functions are belongs to ACF fields only so you can overcome the same process with `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'status' )` and `delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'project_address' )`. Where "status" and "project_address" must be the same text inside `wp_postmeta` table `"meta_key"`. ACF fields save with 2 meta_key `"_status"` and `"status"` so if you want to delete the meta_key, consider to remove 2 fields.